# Ошибка автоматического удаление пакетов в Android

Tags: android, shell, android-adb

Написал скрипт для автоматического удаление софта установленного при продаже.

```
adb shell pm list packages -3 | cut -c 9- | xargs -n 1  -t adb shell pm uninstall -k
```

Вывод такой:

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.gameloft.android.GloftRF15 
Failure
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.opera.branding 
Failure
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.dropbox.android
Failure
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.facebook.katana
Failure
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.tcl.gc
Failure
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.gameloft.android.GAND.GloftCRSM
Failure
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.bbm
Failure
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.trendmicro.freetmms.gmobi
Failure
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.gameloft.android.GloftSMIM
Failure
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.shazam.android
Failure
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.whatsapp
Failure
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.jrdcom.wifitransfer
Failure
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.twitter.android
Failure
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.viber.voip
Failure
adb shell pm uninstall -k flipboard.app
Failure
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.opera.mini.android
Failure
adb shell pm uninstall -k ru.yandex.taxi
Failure
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.gameloft.android.GloftDBMF
Failure
```

Если самому построчно копировать в терминал то работает.
Подскажите в чем проблема?

ОС: Mac OS X El Capitan

Answer (score 1):

возможно, *adb* при запуске делает какую-то блокировку, предотвращающую одновременный запуск нескольких экземпляров.

а их запускается два: тот, который с параметрами `... list packages ...` и тот, который вызывается программой `xargs`.

попробуйте записывать список команд в файл, а затем выполнять их отдельно:

```
$ adb shell pm list packages -3 | cut -c 9- | xargs -n 1 echo adb shell pm uninstall -k > some.file
$ sh some.file
```